# Huawei ML Kit - Image Segmentation App crash when updating to 3.0.0.301

Tags: java, android, machine-learning, huawei-mobile-services, huawei-ml-kit

The app was working perfectly with the previous version :

```
implementation 'com.huawei.hms:ml-computer-vision-segmentation:2.2.0.300'
implementation 'com.huawei.hms:ml-computer-vision-image-segmentation-multiclass-model:2.2.0.300'
implementation 'com.huawei.hms:ml-computer-vision-image-segmentation-body-model:2.2.0.300'
```

Now when I updated to 3.0.0.301 :

```
implementation 'com.huawei.hms:ml-computer-vision-segmentation:3.0.0.301'
implementation 'com.huawei.hms:ml-computer-vision-image-segmentation-multiclass-model:3.0.0.301'
implementation 'com.huawei.hms:ml-computer-vision-image-segmentation-body-model:3.0.0.301'
```

The app crash and I get this message :

> 2021-08-04 00:35:50.103 32383-32383/maa.abc.background_changer
> E/ActivityThread: Failed to find provider info for com.huawei.hms
>
> 2021-08-04 00:35:50.109 32383-32383/maa.abc.background_changer
> E/AbstractInitializer: huawei_module_mlkit_imgseg -> No need to switch
> because the context of the dynamic module is null or the context of
> full sdk
>
> 2021-08-04 00:35:50.109 32383-32383/maa.abc.background_changer
> E/AbstractInitializer: huawei_module_mlkit_imgseg -> The context of
> the dynamic module belongs to LOCAL
>
> 2021-08-04 00:35:50.156 32383-32383/maa.abc.background_changer
> E/HIAI_DDK_MSG: /AiDllParser.cpp Load(45)::"dlopen load lib
> failed,lib[/system/lib64/libhiai_foundation.huawei.so],errmsg [dlopen
> failed: can't read file
> "/data/app/~~tmU2wHTAY38LvsdjeofDpA==/maa.abc.background_changer-QDVrIWUG8BkHCusrq3t_HQ==/lib/arm64":
> Is a directory]"
>
> 2021-08-04 14:02:10.286 7082-7082/? E/HIAI_DDK_MSG:
> /hiai_foundation_dl_helper.c
> HIAI_Foundation_GetSymbol(50)::"HIAI_Foundation_GetSymbol error."
>
> 2021-08-04 14:02:10.286 7082-7082/? E/HIAI_DDK_MSG: /hiai_version.c
> HIAI_GetVersion(66)::"sym HIAI_GetVersion not found."
>
> 2021-08-04 14:02:10.286 7082-7082/? E/HIAI_DDK_MSG: /AiDllParser.cpp
> Load(38)::"Load realpath failed in line 38"
>
> 2021-08-04 14:02:10.286 7082-7082/? E/HIAI_DDK_MSG: /AiDllParser.cpp
> Load(45)::"dlopen load lib
> failed,lib[/vendor/lib64/libai_client.so],errmsg [dlopen failed: can't
> read file
> "/data/app/~~mbQecxD1bZ8erjK-NEO8yw==/com.hauwei.mlkit.sample.gesturechangebackground-2NSWslAh4_jWMK0KxcOV1g==/lib/arm64":
> Is a directory]"
>
> 2021-08-04 14:02:10.286 7082-7082/? E/HIAI_DDK_MSG: /AiDllParser.cpp
> Load(38)::"Load realpath failed in line 38"
>
> 2021-08-04 14:02:10.286 7082-7082/? E/HIAI_DDK_MSG: /AiDllParser.cpp
> Load(45)::"dlopen load lib
> failed,lib[/system/lib64/libhiai_foundation.huawei.so],errmsg [dlopen
> failed: can't read file
> "/data/app/~~mbQecxD1bZ8erjK-NEO8yw==/com.hauwei.mlkit.sample.gesturechangebackground-2NSWslAh4_jWMK0KxcOV1g==/lib/arm64":
> Is a directory]"
>
> 2021-08-04 14:02:10.287 7082-7082/? E/HIAI_DDK_MSG:
> /ops_kernel_store_manager.cpp LoadComputeLibrary(396)::"hook function
> Initialize failed"
>
> 2021-08-04 14:02:10.287 7082-7082/? E/HIAI_DDK_MSG:
> /ops_kernel_store_manager.cpp
> RegComputeLibrary(303)::"RegComputeLibrary call LoadComputeLibrary
> fail"
>
> 2021-08-04 14:02:10.287 7082-7082/? E/V1CL: /rom_interface.cpp
> OpenClient(46)::"Open libai_client.so failed, error: dlopen failed:
> library "/vendor/lib64/libhiai_foundation.so" not found"
>
> 2021-08-04 14:02:10.287 7082-7082/? E/V1CL: /aicpv1cl_initialize.cpp
> Init(29)::"OpenClient failed"
>
> 2021-08-04 14:02:10.287 7082-7082/? E/HIAI_DDK_MSG:
> /ops_kernel_store_manager.cpp LoadComputeLibrary(396)::"hook function
> Initialize failed"
>
> 2021-08-04 14:02:10.287 7082-7082/? E/HIAI_DDK_MSG:
> /ops_kernel_store_manager.cpp
> RegComputeLibrary(303)::"RegComputeLibrary call LoadComputeLibrary
> fail"
>
> 2021-08-04 14:02:10.380 7082-7082/? A/libc: Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV),
> code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0x0 in tid 7082 (hangebackground),
> pid 7082 (hangebackground)

Here's an example of my code:

```
public class ImageSegmentation {

    private MLImageSegmentationAnalyzer analyzer;

    public void analyzer(Bitmap src, MLCallBack mlCallBack) {
        MLImageSegmentationSetting setting = new MLImageSegmentationSetting.Factory()
                .setExact(true)
                .setAnalyzerType(MLImageSegmentationSetting.BODY_SEG)
                .setScene(MLImageSegmentationScene.FOREGROUND_ONLY)
                .create();
        this.analyzer = MLAnalyzerFactory.getInstance().getImageSegmentationAnalyzer(setting);
        MLFrame mlFrame = new MLFrame.Creator().setBitmap(src).create();
        Task<MLImageSegmentation> task = this.analyzer.asyncAnalyseFrame(mlFrame);
        task.addOnSuccessListener(imageSegmentationResult -> {
            if (imageSegmentationResult != null) mlCallBack.onMLCompleted(imageSegmentationResult);
            else mlCallBack.onMLFailed();
        }).addOnFailureListener(e -> mlCallBack.onMLFailed());
    }

}
```

**Gradle :**

```
repositories {
    jcenter()
    mavenCentral()
    google()
    maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    maven { url "http://dl.bintray.com/vsmaks/maven" }
    maven { url "http://dl.bintray.com/dasar/maven" }
    maven { url 'https://developer.huawei.com/repo/' }
    maven() { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots" }
    maven {
        url "http://dl.bintray.com/piasy/maven"
    }
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.2.2'
    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
}
```

**Android Studio version : Android Studio arctic fox 2020.3.1**

Thank you.

The app crashes on :

***Huawei P8 Lite 2017 running Android 8.0***

***Xiaomi POCO X3 NFC running Android 11.0***

Comment: How are you testing (device or emulator)? Side note, all of public facing Huawei documentation in EN appears to use the older version.

Comment: @MorrisonChang thank you so much for your comment, I've tested the app on two devices (Huawei and Xiaomi) the app crashes on the both of them

Comment: You should update your post with details of devices (model number/OS version etc.)

Comment: @MorrisonChang I've updated my question, in fact, I've found someone facing the same issue in the [Huawei Developer forum](https://forums.developer.huawei.com/forumPortal/en/topic/0202630340816550019), the app crash on other device brands such as OPPO, Samsung

Comment: I recommend model numbers as well since regional variations exist. I would also post  on the official Huawei dev forum as well along with the info the Huawei team asked for in that thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for your feedback. The R&D team confirms that the version 3.0.0.301 is faulty. Therefore, it is recommended that you use an earlier version of the ML kit, which has been modified in the current document.

[image]

For more details, You can refer to this [Docs](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/hiai-Guides/seg-sdk-0000001050038094).

Comment: Hi @zhangxaochen Thanks for your post I have tried this everything works perfectly but google play store not accept my app with 2.2.0.300.